# An iOS app with multiple brandings

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an iphone app working just fine - it basically just displays news from a feed, but now we want to have a second app that is a clone of the first but branded a different way and displaying news from a different feed - the xml feed and the graphics/colors would be the only difference.

I'm trying to not duplicate any effort. I can easily set a define and build the app using different colors and images and the xml feed url with one codebase. But what is the preferred way to do this so that I can make a change to some common code and easily rebuild both apps and get them updated in the app store without maintaining separate xcode projects, separate files, etc?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this easily by adding a new target to your project.

Create unique branded assets and configuration files with identical names, but keep them in different folders. When you're ready, add each folder to the project and set the "Target Membership" to the appropriate target. If you make a mistake, you can change it in the File Inspector pane.

When you build a specific target from the shared codebase, only those resources will be bundled with the app. As long as the filenames are identical, it should work.

Comment: can You give solutions when discussion is going about the classes which contain URLs to the server. What is the best way in this situation to do one class(with all of it's logics) workable for all brands?

Answer (score 1):

You can use one project with more then one target. For each target you can add different resources (Info.plist, icon, etc.).
XML feed can be defined in settings.bundle (which also can be dependent on the target).
Layout you can read from dictionary, which also should be dependent on the target.

Comment: Ah - I'm new to this and didn't understand the purpose of the targets. Thank you!