# App Icons for Paid and Free app in the same target

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to change the app icon for both the free and paid version. I am not sure how to do that and have found no luck on the internet. Does anyone know how to do this?

From what i have read is that you have to select which target it goes to but other than that i have found nothing.

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975729/two-versions-of-ios-app-free-and-paid-how-to-conditionally-change-project-id

Comment: yes i did see that. That still doesn't explain how to set a different icon for each one. I tried that solution and it still didn't work. It doesn't explain how to set each one to a different target. I have hundreds of images. How would xcode know that i want those two specific folders as the icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understood is that you need to duplicate your target folder and make necessary changes in your project like resources, images etc. Then you need to build your project targeting Free or Paid version. Nice article explained here, http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2098
If you have already followed the guideline then please post the error you are receiving.